# android phonegap webview

Tags: android, webview, cordova

hello all i am very new to `phonegap`.. i want to webview into my application how can i add this? i've created same app. using android but how it can devleope using `PHONEGAP`?

```
 private WebView mWebView;
    //bla bla bla..
        @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewHelp);

                    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();

                    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyjavascriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
                    mWebView.loadUrl(strURL);
                    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
                }   
                public class MyjavascriptInterface {
                    public void showHTML(String html)
                    {
                        bla bla bla...
                    }
                }
                public class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

                    @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        bla bla bla...
                    }
                    }
                    }
```

thanks in advance :Pragna

Answer (score 2):

For your most basic PhoneGap app you should extend your main activity from DroidGap.

```
import com.phonegap.DroidGap;

public class Main extends DroidGap {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

//private Button m_button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out [this link](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/35501397/Tutorials) for a series of tutorials using Phonegap within the Eclipse development environment. Once you are setup on eclipse, you only need to overide a few lines of code in the Android Activity class to call your web pages. Phonegap takes care of the rest in terms of opening up a webview class and rendering your html within it. You will no longer to code that yourself (as you've done above). The tutorials spell it out quite clearly. You can also add your own custom JavaScript interface methods as well. Again that's described in the tutorials. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your case there is a need to **Embedding Cordova WebView on Android** here is [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html) for it

Modify your main Activity as

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CordovaInterface {
    CordovaWebView cwv;
    /* Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        cwv = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.tutorialView);
        cwv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
```

And in your layout replace your webview with

```
<org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView
    android:id="@+id/tutorialView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```